# Sci2, Eclipse and "Unable to acquire application service" on Windows 10

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I have downloaded the Sci2 application (an Eclipse based tool for bibliometrics) and installed it on two Windows 10 systems. On one system (the desktop) it starts up and runs without a problem. On the other (a new laptop) it fails to start with the following error in the log file:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started
```

The commonly suggested solution to include "org.eclipse.core.runtime@start" in the config.ini file does, not surprisingly, not work as the first (identical) installation on the desktop computer runs as expected, and thus the config.ini file is correct.

It obviously must have something to do with differences in what else is installed on the two systems and how the systems are configured, but I cannot figure out for the life of me where even to look for the source of the problem. The Windows versions on the two systems are identical, as are the Java versions installed.

Also noticed that on the working desktop system, the application creates additional directories (after startup, not during installation) in the configuration folder:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime
org.eclipse.equinox.app
.settings
```

These folders are not not being created on the other system (the laptop). Just copying these folders over unfortunately does not resolve the issue either.

Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with 32-bit / 64-bit version of Sci2 and Java, and reinstalling the 64-bit JRE, the application starts up again as expected.

Still don't know the specific issues that caused the problem, but at least it works now. Must say the error message in the log file is very confusing.